# using a powerful connection tool for strong results...

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Problem:

Let $\phi :M\rightarrow N$ be a local homeo. with M and N topological spaces. Let $f :X\rightarrow M$ and $g :X\rightarrow M$ be contiuous functions such that $\phi o f=\phi og:X\rightarrow N$.

Show that, if X is connected and there exist $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=g(x)$, then $f=g$.

My attempt:

I write the set $C=\left\lbrace x\in X:f(x)=g(x)\right\rbrace$. I must only prove that $C=X$, for this, because $C$ is connected, I must only show that $C$ is clopen. I get to prove that $C$ is open, but, I have problems with to show $C$ is close.

My problems:

For to prove $C$ is close, I suppose it isn't. Then there exist a acumulation point, $a$, what doesn't belong to $C$, i.e., $f(a)\neq g(a)$. For supposition by problem, there exist open sets $U$ and $U'$ on M such that $f(a)\in U$, $g(a)\in U'$  and $\phi |_{U}$ and $\phi |_{U'}$ are homeo. As $f$ and $g$ are continuous, then $f^{-1}(U)$ and $g^{-1}(U')$ are open, so $f^{-1}(U) \cap g^{-1}(U')$ is open on X, even more, $a\in f^{-1}(U) \cap g^{-1}(U')$ and as $a$ is a acumulation point, there exist a point within $f^{-1}(U) \cap g^{-1}(U')$...after of this, I want to arrive to the contradition that there not exist a point what belongs to $f^{-1}(U) \cap g^{-1}(U') \cap C$, but I don't get to arrive to this...

could somebody help me?...

Comment: Do you assume that $M$ is Hausdorff?

Comment: No, I did not assume that...

Answer (score 1):

If $M$ is not Hausdorff, then this may not be true.

For instance, consider $M=[0,1]\cup \{0'\}$, the interval with doubled endpoint (which is about as nice as a non-Hausdorff space can be) and $X=N=[0,1]$ with $\phi\colon M\to N$ being the standard projection and $f(x)=g(x)=x$ for $x>0$, $f(0)=0$, $g(0)=0'$.

Then $\phi$ is a local homeomorphism, and $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\neq 0$ and $f\circ \phi=g\circ \phi=\operatorname{id}_{[0,1]}$, and yet $f\neq g$.

If $M$ is Hausdorff, on the other hand, then $C$ is trivially closed: just consider the appropriate function $X\to M^2$.

Comment: I don't understand you completely. why is g continuous?....because, if you're considere $\left\lbrace 0'\right\rbrace$ on $M$ as an open set, then $g^{-1}(\left\lbrace 0'\right\rbrace )=\left\lbrace 0\right\rbrace $ must be a open set, however $\left\lbrace 0\right\rbrace $ isn't an open set...

Comment: No, $\{0'\}$ is not open. The neighbourhoods of $0'$ look like neighbourhoods of $0$, with $0'$ swapped with $0$.

Comment: @JELV see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Hausdorff_manifold#Line_with_two_origins

Comment: ohh I didn't know that topology. You're absolutely right. I carry me something quite useful. Thank you so much!

Comment: @JELV: Happy to help. If you like an answer to your question, you should accept it and upvote it (by clicking he tick sign and the up arrow).